# Code Sign Error - codesign: Unknown error: -22

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5, codesign

i'm getting this error when i try to run my app on real device. Can anyone help me to solve?

PS. provisioning and signing identity are setted correctly.. in fact, until a few hours ago everything worked fine

```
CodeSign /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MilitariTest-eckbgmqsefbhupgakvywpmavdthi/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MilitariTest.app
    cd /Users/user/Desktop/MilitariTest/MilitariTest
    export CODESIGN_ALLOCATE=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/codesign_allocate
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    Using code signing identity "iPhone Developer" and provisioning profile "iOS Team Provisioning Profile" (XXXXX)
    /usr/bin/codesign --force --sign XXXXX --resource-rules=/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MilitariTest-eckbgmqsefbhupgakvywpmavdthi/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MilitariTest.app/ResourceRules.plist --entitlements /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MilitariTest-eckbgmqsefbhupgakvywpmavdthi/Build/Intermediates/MilitariTest.build/Debug-iphoneos/MilitariTest.build/MilitariTest.xcent /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MilitariTest-eckbgmqsefbhupgakvywpmavdthi/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MilitariTest.app

sh: /usr/bin/codesign: Unknown error: -22
```

---

**i finally found a solution, i had to reinstall mac os x, now all working well, without any change to the project**

Comment: Do you have a apple developer account?

Comment: If you just want to test your app in device, no need to use the `iOS Team Provisioning Profile`. Just select `none` for provision profile.

Comment: @Danyun obviously already have an developer developer

Comment: @GoGreen even if I select none, i get the same error

Comment: @user3746280  do you add your device to the profile which you used in the project.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to remove your derived data.

- There are two ways to remove your app derived data.
- 1)  Go to this path  press **shift+Commmand+G** and enter this path
  There you will find your  application folder just remove that don't worry.

  **~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData**
- 2) From Xcode Window>organizer>projects> select your app and press
  **delete**.